# Converting a stand alone java file to a file that's part of a project package?

Tags: java

I still don't fully understand where I'm required to use the "public static void main(String[] args)" header within the .java files of a project. Do you need to put that header in every .java file of a package?

I have been following along with chapter 3 in my book, dragging and dropping downloaded stand alone book source files into my project's package, but some of the .java files in my package don't like that "public static void main(String[] args)" statement, even though my opening and closing curly braces are in the correct place. Here's an example of one of those files (the ERROR(S) are described in the code's comments):

```
    public class Rectangle
{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   private double length;//ERROR: illegal start of expression
   private double width;

   /**
    * Constructor
    */

   public Rectangle(double len, double w)
   {
      length = len;
      width = w;
   }

   /**
    * The setLength method accepts an argument
    * that is stored in the length field. 
    */

   public void setLength(double len)
   {
      length = len;
   }

   /**
    * The setWidth method accepts an argument
    * that is stored in the width field.
    */

   public void setWidth(double w)
   {
      width = w;
   }

   /**
    * The set method accepts two arguments
    * that are stored in the length and width
    * fields.
    */

   public void set(double len, double w)
   {
      length = len;
      width = w;
   }

   /**
    * The getLength method returns the value
    * stored in the length field.
    */

   public double getLength()
   {
      return length;
   }

   /**
    * The getWidth method returns the value
    * stored in the width field.
    */

   public double getWidth()
   {
      return width;
   }

   /**
    * The getArea method returns the value of the
    * length field times the width field.
    */

   public double getArea()
   {
      return length * width;
   }

}//end of: public static void main(String[] args)

}//end of: public class Rectangle  ERROR: class, interface, or enum expected
```

The ERROR(S) came up after I added the "public static void main(String[] args)" to the existing Rectangle.java file. Any idea of why this occurs?

Comment: No you should not. the main header must exists only in one class of the package since compiler only runs one class that contains main statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
private double length;
```

The error is because you cannot have access modifiers for a method local variable. Access modifiers are used on class variables. Access level modifiers determine whether other classes can use a particular field or invoke a particular method.

**In the Java programming language, every application must contain a main method** whose signature is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

**But that does not mean that every class in your application should contain a main method.** The main method is similar to the main function in C and C++; it's the entry point for your application and will subsequently invoke all the other methods required by your program.

I would recommend you to understand the anatomy of a java application, classes, access modifiers before you jump into writing programs and get yourself totally confused. Here are few links to link to help you:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

`main` is simply a method name.  By convention, when you use the `java <someclass>` command, that command looks for a `main` method with a certain signature (set of parms) in `<someclass>` and invokes that method as the entry point to the Java application.

There is no rule saying that you can't have a `main` method in every class, but only the one in the class named on the `java` command line has any special significance beyond being just another method.

That said, to avoid confusion it's best to avoid using `main` as a method name, except where you intend for it to be the "main entry point" of the application.

Your error is simply because you have invalid syntax -- you did not enter a complete method when you added `main`.

Answer (score -2):

This occurs because You cannot have more than one `main()` method in a package. However overriding the main method is definitely allowed. What I mean is as, long the parameter number is differed you can override `main()` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   .....
}
```

And somewhere else in other or same class, you can add such class

```
public static void main(String arg1, String arg2) {
    .....
}
```

The **`ERROR: illegal start of expression`** is because you are using access modifier inside the method. Use all the access mofifier and variable declaration inside the class

```
public class Rectangle {

    private double length;//ERROR: illegal start of expression   
    private double width;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ....
    }
}
```

The **`ERROR: class, interface, or enum expected`** is because the class `Rectangle` is only housing a static method, your all the methods and parameters are inside the static method called `main()`

**[Here](http://pastebin.com/03HgbqM9) is your code which will compile without an error.**

Comment: Thanks. I also found this the other day:

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java.html

It seems to be a very good source for beginner 
java tutorials.